# Append a column values from multiple rows into a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is this valid SQL to append the values of a column for several records into a single string result?

```
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Result = ''

SELECT @Result = @Result + Answer + ';'
FROM Answers A
WHERE A.Quiz_ID = 1 AND A.Question_Id = 1
ORDER BY Answer

Select @Result [List Of Answers]
```

The result should look like this:

```
Can You Repeat The Question;No;Yes;
```

This is only an example. My question is is this valid SQL? The reason I ask is that this technique seems to break down in my real code with more joins and an ORDER BY clause. In my "real" code I only get the value from one row.

Comment: have you tried running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your goal you need to use `STUFF()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT q.Question + ';' +
       STUFF((SELECT ';' + Answer
                FROM Answers
               WHERE Question_Id = q.Question_Id
               ORDER BY 1
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') result
  FROM Questions q LEFT JOIN Answers a
    ON q.Question_Id = a.Question_Id
 GROUP BY q.Question_Id, q.Question
```

Sample output:

```
|                                      RESULT |
-----------------------------------------------
|    Can You Repeat The Question;Maybe;No;Yes |
| Can You Really Repeat The Question;Sure;Yes |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1aae/1)** demo

If there is a possibility of having questions without answers being assigned yet and you want to properly show them you may use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` (e.g. to inject a default value)

```
SELECT q.Question + ';' +
       ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ';' + Answer
                FROM Answers
               WHERE Question_Id = q.Question_Id
               ORDER BY 1
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''), 
       '[Sorry, no answers yet]') result
  FROM Questions q LEFT JOIN Answers a
    ON q.Question_Id = a.Question_Id
  GROUP BY q.Question_Id, q.Question
```

Sample output:

```
|                                                 RESULT |
----------------------------------------------------------
|               Can You Repeat The Question;Maybe;No;Yes |
|            Can You Really Repeat The Question;Sure;Yes |
| Can a question have no answers;[Sorry, no answers yet] |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70f26/7)** demo

Comment: Thanks for the SQLFiddle demo